# DC and crossfilter joining datasets that are at different levels

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I am creating a budget versus actuals dashboard using dc.js.

I have two datasets.

A budget dataset which consists of budget values by category:

```
var budget = [
  {category: "groceries", amount: 2000},
  {category: "medical", amount: 100},
  {category: "phone", amount: 200}
];
```

An actuals datasets which contains individual transactions which belong to a category:

```
var actuals = [
   {date: "2015-01-01", description: "coles online", value: 210, category: "groceries"},
   {date: "2015-01-02", description: "fruit shop", value: 25, category: "groceries"},
   {date: "2015-01-03", description: "health shop", value: 75, category: "groceries"},
   {date: "2015-01-06", description: "doctor", value: 80, category: "medical"},
   {date: "2015-01-03", description: "phone bill", value: 75, category: "phone"}
];
```

I would like to create a graph that shows actuals versus budget by category.  This could be a grouped row chart, stacked row chart (where one of the stacks would be budget - actual) or even a stacked bar chart.  I'd even be happy with a simple row chart by category where the budget bar, followed the actuals bar e.g. Actuals - Groceries, Budget - Groceries.

However, my basic problem is how to combine the two datasets given that one is at category level and one is at the lower transaction level?

Could I maybe hack the crossfilter group for the actuals to add in the budget figures?  I suspect there's a better way.

Comment: I think you can probably combine them into a single array and then create a group that aggregates 2 values - the budget "amount" and the actual "value". Since the 2 datasets use different properties for the value to be aggregated, this should work.

Comment: Ok. I think I follow. So I produce a single dataset that has the transactions with a null budget "amount" UNIONed with the budget "amount"s which will have null actual "value" figures.  And better yet, rename the fields to something less confusing! Will try this and then take a look at the grouping.

Comment: Yes, just make sure to convert your nulls to 0s at some point. Usually you'll want to do this using a group accessor function (e.g. ```dimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return +d; })```), though you'll need a custom group function to do this. It's not terribly complicated, but if you're having trouble, you can check out Reductio, which supports this type of grouping with Crossfilter.